# Fetch the list of all txt files in directory and sub directory and add it to a List

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

Trying to fetch the list of all text files in directory/sub-directory and and add it to a List

Structure:

```
sampleDirFolder->testDirFolder->test.txt,test1.txt
```

Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class testClass {

//Method to read dir/sub-dir and get list of .java files
public static List<String> listFiles(String path)

{
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] files = folder.listFiles();
    for (File file : files)
    { if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt"))
    {
        System.out.println(file.getName());
    }
    else if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        listFiles(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    }
    return listOfFiles;
}

public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
    listFiles("path/Desktop/sampledir");
}
}
```

OP:

```
test.txt
test1.txt
```

This code works for printing the list of files, any suggestions on how to add it to a `List<String>`

Comment: 1. Create a List. 2. Every time you find a file, add it to the List. 3. Return the List. 4. Add all elements from the returned List to the List.

Comment: @Amongalen when I try to add the file name to a list in the function, it returns only a empty list.

Comment: You should show us what you have tried. Current code won't even compile because there is no `listOfFiles` variable.

Comment: You could use the java 7 Files#walkFileTree feature. If you're new to java, it can be somewhat complicated to understand, but it's a very compact solution: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class testClass {

//Method to read dir/sub-dir and get list of .java files
public static void listFiles(String path, List<String> filesList)

{
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] files = folder.listFiles();
    for (File file : files)
    { if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt"))
    {
        //System.out.println(file.getName());
        filesList.add(file.getName());
    }
    else if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        listFiles(file.getAbsolutePath(), filesList);
    }
    }
    //return listOfFiles;
}

public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> filesList = new ArrayList<>();
    listFiles("path/Desktop/sampledir", filesList);
    System.out.println(filesList);
}
}
```

Comment: The else part is wrong, the code won't compile. You're calling `listFiles(file.getAbsolutePath());` while there is no method with single parameter. You need to pass the list in there as well.

Comment: Yes, I am getting this exact error described in the comment